# Erro na consulta ao banco de dados com cakephp-2

Tags: cakephp-2

Gostaria de saber o que há de errado com minha consulta. Estou debugando ela, e está trazendo todos os resultados do model RegistroHorario e não apenas um resultado por usuário, ou seja, as partes de "fields", "group" e "order" não estão sendo consideradas.

```
$us['joins'] =  array(
array(
    'table' => 'registro_horarios',
    'alias' => 'RegistroHorario',
    'type'  => 'LEFT',
    'fields' => array(
        '(SELECT cliente_id 
            FROM registro_horarios m
            WHERE m.user_id = registro_horarios.user_id
            ORDER BY data_fim DESC LIMIT 1) as cliente_id',
        'RegistroHorario.user_id'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id = RegistroHorario.id'
    ),
    'group' => 'RegistroHorario.user_id',
    'order' => 'RegistroHorario.MAX(data_fim) DESC'
));

$us['fields'] = array(
                'User.id'
);

$this->loadModel('User');

$usuarios = $this->User->find('all', $us);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei uma solução alternativa para o que eu queria fazer, é feia mas resolve o problema:

```
public function qtdColaboradores(){
    $sql = 'SELECT (SELECT cliente_id
      from registro_horarios m
      where m.user_id = registro_horarios.user_id
      order by data_fim DESC LIMIT 1) as cliente_id,
      user_id
      FROM intranet.registro_horarios
      group by user_id
      order by MAX(data_fim) desc;';
    return $this->query($sql);
  }
```